# checkbox is not working properly

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, jhipster

checkbox which is in table header is not working and how to delete record using checkbox

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('banksApp')
        .controller('HdfcController', HdfcController);

    HdfcController.$inject = ['$scope', '$state', 'Hdfc', 'ParseLinks', 'AlertService'];

    function HdfcController ($scope, $state, Hdfc, ParseLinks, AlertService) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.hdfcs = [];
        vm.loadPage = loadPage;
        vm.page = 0;
        vm.links = {
            last: 0
        };
        vm.predicate = 'id';
        vm.reset = reset;
        vm.reverse = true;
        vm.checkAll = [];
        var map = {};
        vm.checkboxes = [];
        vm.selectedItems = [];

        vm.selectAll = selectAll;
        vm.select = select;

        loadAll();

        function loadAll () {
            Hdfc.query({
                page: vm.page,
                size: 20,
                sort: sort()
            }, onSuccess, onError);
            function sort() {
                var result = [vm.predicate + ',' + (vm.reverse ? 'asc' : 'desc')];
                if (vm.predicate !== 'id') {
                    result.push('id');
                }
                return result;
            }

            function onSuccess(data, headers) {
                vm.links = ParseLinks.parse(headers('link'));
                vm.totalItems = headers('X-Total-Count');
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    vm.hdfcs.push(data[i]);
                }
            }

            function onError(error) {
                AlertService.error(error.data.message);
            }
        }

        function reset () {
            vm.page = 0;
            vm.hdfcs = [];
            loadAll();
        }

        function loadPage(page) {
            vm.page = page;
            loadAll();
        }
    
    
        function selectAll () {
            var value = vm.checkAll[vm.page];
            angular.forEach(vm.hdfcs, function(item) {
                if (angular.isDefined(item.id)) {
                    if(vm.checkboxes[item.id] != value) {
                        vm.checkboxes[item.id] = value;
                        vm.select(item);
                    }
                }
           });
        };

        function select (item) {
            var value = vm.checkboxes[item.id];

            if(value) {
                vm.selectedItems.push(item);
                if(map[vm.page] == null) map[vm.page] = 1;
                else map[vm.page] = map[vm.page] + 1;
                if(map[vm.page] == vm.hdfcs.length) {
                    vm.checkAll[vm.page] = true;
                }
            } else {
                vm.selectedItems.splice(item, 1);
                if(map[vm.page] == null) map[vm.page] = 0;
                else map[vm.page] = map[vm.page] - 1;
                if(map[vm.page] < vm.hdfcs.length) {
                    vm.checkAll[vm.page] = false;
                }
            }
        };
        
    }
})();
```

```html
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="jh-table table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr jh-sort="vm.predicate" ascending="vm.reverse" callback="vm.reset()">
                    <th jh-sort-by="id"><span>ID</span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></span></th>
                    <th jh-sort-by="check"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.selectedAll" ng-click="vm.checkAll[vm.page]" /></th>
                    <th jh-sort-by="bankName"><span>Bank Name</span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></span></th>
                    <th jh-sort-by="rejectedRemarks"><span>Rejected Remarks</span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></span></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody infinite-scroll="vm.loadPage(vm.page + 1)" infinite-scroll-disabled="vm.page >= vm.links['last']">
                <tr ng-repeat="hdfc in vm.hdfcs track by hdfc.id">
                    <td><a ui-sref="hdfc-detail({id:hdfc.check})">{{hdfc.check}}</a></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox"  ng-model="vm.checkboxes[hdfc.id]" ng-change="vm.select(hdfc)"/></td>
                    <td>{{($index + 1) + (vm.page - 1) * vm.itemsPerPage}}</td>
                    <td>{{hdfc.bankName}}</td>
                    <td>{{hdfc.rejectedRemarks}}</td>
                    <td class="text-right">
                        <div class="btn-group flex-btn-group-container">
                            <button type="submit"
                                    ui-sref="hdfc-detail({check:hdfc.check})"
                                    class="btn btn-info btn-sm">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>
                                <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"></span>
                            </button>
                            <button type="submit"
                                    ui-sref="hdfc.edit({check:hdfc.check})"
                                    class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                                <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"></span>
                            </button>
                            <button type="submit"
                                    ui-sref="hdfc.delete({check:hdfc.check})"
                                    class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
                                <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"></span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

`
        
            
                
                    ID 
                    
                    Bank Name 
                    Rejected Remarks 
                    
                
            
            = vm.links['last']">
                
                    {{hdfc.check}}
                    
                    {{($index + 1) + (vm.page - 1) * vm.itemsPerPage}}
                    {{hdfc.bankName}}
                    {{hdfc.rejectedRemarks}}

Comment: Define 'is not working' ?

Comment: it means when I clicked on checkbox which is in table header(for select All checkboxes) then it will error:internalservererror

Comment: and how to delete the row or rows using checkbox

Comment: Use `ng-Checked`  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked and debug it

Comment: @Cruzer I am using that checkbox in jhipster. I have tested that whatever you said and result is I got checkbox in form as well.

Comment: I think you need to use `ng-click="vm.checkAll = vm.page"` instead of `ng-click="vm.checkAll[vm.page]"`

Comment: its not still working

Answer (score 0):

Use splice function to delete record.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>TASKS</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">

<div ng-controller="sampleController">
   <h3>To do</h3>
   <table class="table table-striped table-hover col-sm-4">
       <thead>
           <tr>
              <th>Task</th>
              <th>Time</th>
              <th>Done</th>
     <th><input type="checkbox" ng-model="allSelected" ng-click="selectAll()"/> Select All</th>
     <th><input type="button" value="delete All Rows" ng-show="allSelected" ng-click="deleteAllRows()"/></th>
     <th><input type="button" value="Reset Data" ng-click="ResetData()"/></th>
           </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody ng-repeat="x in firstTable">
<tr>
    <td>x.taskName</td>
   <td> x.tastTime</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="seletedTasks[$index]"/></td>
   <td><input type="button" value="Delete Selected Row" ng-show="seletedTasks[$index]" ng-click="deleteRow($index)"/>
</tr>
          
       </tbody>
   </table>
   
  
 

</div>
</body>
<script>
var app=angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller("sampleController",["$scope",function($scope){
$scope.firstTable=[{taskName:'Task_One',tastTime:'5 min'},{taskName:'Task_Two',tastTime:'2 min'},{taskName:'Task_Three',tastTime:'2 min'}];
$scope.seletedTasks=[];

$scope.ResetData=function(){
$scope.firstTable=[{taskName:'Task_One',tastTime:'5 min'},{taskName:'Task_Two',tastTime:'2 min'},{taskName:'Task_Three',tastTime:'2 min'}];
$scope.secondTable=[];
$scope.seletedTasks=[];
$scope.allSelected=false;
}
$scope.deleteAllRows=function(){
$scope.firstTable=[];
$scope.seletedTasks=[];
$scope.allSelected=false;
};
$scope.deleteRow=function(index){
$scope.seletedTasks.splice(index,1);
$scope.firstTable.splice(index,1);
};
$scope.selectAll=function(){
if($scope.allSelected){
angular.forEach($scope.firstTable,function(value,index){
$scope.seletedTasks[index]=true;
});
}
};

}]);
</script>
</html>
```